# Prefer fetch_and_add or add_and_fetch?

Tags: c, atomic

I'm using [GCC's atomic builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) to increment a shared `volatile int`. All I want to do is increment the value, and I don't care about the return value. Should I prefer `fetch_and_add` or `add_and_fetch` for this? I don't see anything in the documentation suggesting one would have a performance benefit over the other. Does it really not matter?

Alternatively, since I don't actually need to read the value atomically, is there a better way to increment a `volatile int` since I don't actually read the return value?

This is obviously architecture dependent, so you can assume I'm using x64. I'm specifically using AMD Opteron CPUs if that makes a difference.

Comment: it's just a hunch, but it could be hardware dependent... measure it.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - Yes, that's true. I updated the question to make it more clear that I'm on a fairly standard x64 system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your hardware, depend on the size of your variable, on the increment value and on your compiler options.

To check it, translate a little C program in to assembly.

```
volatile int init;
void foo(void) {
    __sync_fetch_and_add(&init,1);
    __sync_add_and_fetch(&init,1);
}
```

Translates with 'gcc -S x.c' into a file x.s.
The most interesting in x.s is

```
    lock addl       $1, init(%rip)
    lock addl       $1, init(%rip)
```

That shows the two intrinsics are translated into the same assembler codes (here on Intel x64).

You could also try it with -march=native and/or -O3 or your favourite options just to see if it is always the same...